# jQuery: how to display progress for an indeterminate process?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The [documentation on the jQuery progressBar](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar)
says that this UI widget is not suitable for displaying progress of indeterminate length.

It recommends one of two alternatives:
- an indeterminate progressBar, which is "coming soon".
- a spinner animation

I think [a jQuery spinner is a textbox with up/down arrows](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Spinner) to inc/dec the value. In other words, an input widget.

[image]

That can't be what the doc meant.

**using jQuery, How do I display indeterminate progress?**

Comment: The "spinner" in this more correctly known as a "throbber": a name which has always made me giggle like a little schoolgirl.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throbber

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By spinner, I think they mean an animated graphic which endlessly loops, or spins. Like this:
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
<div id="pb"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#pb").progressbar({ value: 100 });
    IndeterminateProgressBar($("#pb"));
});
function IndeterminateProgressBar(pb) {
    $(pb).css({ "padding-left": "0%", "padding-right": "90%" });
    $(pb).progressbar("option", "value", 100);
    $(pb).animate({ paddingLeft: "90%", paddingRight: "0%" }, 1000, "linear",
        function () { IndeterminateProgressBar(pb); });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

More like:

[image: Loading]
<sub>(source: [vinofordinner.com](http://vinofordinner.com/art/loading.gif))</sub>

or

[image: Loading]

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is not a jQuery question... it's just a matter of animation.

You'll probably be fine by displaying an animated image just like the ones available from e.g. [Ajax Load](http://ajaxload.info/)

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late to the party, but here's a plugin that leverages the jQuery UI Progressbar for an indeterminate progress bar:

http://demo.dochoffiday.com/jquery-loader/

Also, there are plans to include the indeterminate feature in the future:

http://blog.jqueryui.com/2010/12/progressbar-api-redesign/